# Angular 5 it overwrites always the selected date with the current date

Tags: html, angular, typescript, reducers

I have an input field which has a date into it but the problem is that when I wan't to select a date which is not the today date everytime takes the current date and saved in the backend.
I want if in the input field is selected for example 15.11.2018 that will be saved.
At the save method in the console log it tells me the right thing I only think the problem it is in the reducers

This is my code

```
<app-input-field label="{{'general.#date'|translate}}">
                    <input type="date" step="1" [ngModel]="newCosts.choosenDate| date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="newCosts.choosenDate = $event">
                </app-input-field>

save() {
    this.newCosts.choosenDate = new Date(this.newCosts.choosenDate)
    this.store.dispatch(new UpsertCostsAction({
        costs: { ...this.newCosts } 

    }))
    this.newCosts = emptyCosts()
}

export interface Costs {
    id: string     
    choosenDate: Date
}
export function emptyCosts(): Costs {
    return {
        id: "",
        choosenDate: new Date(),

    }
}
```

Reducers

```
function toCostsViewModel(costs: Costs): Costs {
    costs.choosenDate = new Date(costs.choosenDate)

    return costs
}

function upsertCosts(state: ValueItemDatabaseState, action: UpsertCostsInternalAction): ValueItemDatabaseState {
    action.payload.forEach(cost => {
        state.costs = state.costs.set(cost.id, toCostsViewModel(cost))
    })
    return {
        ...state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your save method

```
save() {
    this.newCosts.choosenDate = new Date(this.newCosts.choosenDate)
    this.store.dispatch(new UpsertCostsAction({
        costs: { ...this.newCosts } 

    }))
    this.newCosts = emptyCosts()
}
```

at the and you run `this.newCosts = emptyCosts()` and `emptycosts` does overwrite your  `choosenDate: new Date()` basically creating a new now date.

Are you able to confirm?

Comment: I have already found a solution for this, in the backend it was overwritting a new Date